# SymmetricDS: change operation from update to insert/delete in a table transformation

Tags: database, synchronization, symmetricds

on my source table i have a boolean column and if the boolean is switched on SymmetricDS should insert a row into my target table. If it was switched off it should the (eventually) inserted row from target table.

After reading the [Documentation](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.7/html/user-guide.html#_operation_change) these operation change was not possible. 
Any hint how can i build a workaround with the existing capabilities?

my current setup (for an update at source it can only insert at target, not delete from FP_HIST)

```
insert into sym_trigger (TRIGGER_ID, SOURCE_SCHEMA_NAME, SOURCE_TABLE_NAME, CHANNEL_ID, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATE_TIME
, SYNC_ON_INSERT, SYNC_ON_DELETE, SYNC_ON_UPDATE, SYNC_ON_UPDATE_CONDITION) 
VALUES ('eventattendee2fphist', 'webapps_base', 'eventattendee', 'channel_fphist', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
, 0, 0, 1, 'new.attended AND new.id IN (select eat.id from webapps_base.eventattendee eat JOIN webapps_base.iacontact iac ON eat.fk_person_id = iac.fk_naturalperson_id AND NOT iac.lateregistration AND iac.access_path != ''FP_LATE_REGISTRATION'' JOIN webapps_base.event e ON e.id = eat.fk_event_id JOIN webapps_base.eventtypecatalog et ON et.id = e.fk_eventtypecatalog_id AND et.type = ''FP'' JOIN webapps_base.eventagencyassociations eag ON e.id = eag.fk_event_id JOIN webapps_base.agency ag ON ag.id = eag.fk_agency_id WHERE eat.attended)');

insert into SYM_TRIGGER_ROUTER (trigger_id, router_id, initial_load_order, create_time, LAST_UPDATE_TIME, ENABLED) 
values ('eventattendee2fphist', 'pg2ib', 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 1);

insert into SYM_TRANSFORM_TABLE (
  transform_id, source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, transform_point, SOURCE_SCHEMA_NAME, source_table_name,
  target_table_name, delete_action, transform_order, column_policy, update_first) 
values ('eventattendee2fphist', 'postgres', 'interbase', 'EXTRACT', 'webapps_base', 'eventattendee',
'FP_HIST', 'DEL_ROW', 1, 'SPECIFIED', 0);

insert into SYM_TRANSFORM_COLUMN (
  transform_id, include_on, target_column_name, source_column_name, pk,
  transform_type, transform_expression, transform_order) 
values ('eventattendee2fphist', '*', 'PVP', 'fk_Person_ID', 1, 'lookup', 'select ident FROM webapps_base.salespartner where fk_person_id = CAST(:fk_Person_ID AS BIGINT)', 1);


insert into SYM_TRANSFORM_COLUMN (
  transform_id, include_on, target_column_name, source_column_name, pk,
  transform_type, transform_expression, transform_order) 
values
('eventattendee2fphist', '*', 'VP',  'id',           0, 'lookup', 'select br.ident from webapps_base.eventattendee eat JOIN webapps_base.iacontact iac ON eat.fk_person_id = iac.fk_naturalperson_id AND NOT iac.lateregistration AND iac.access_path != ''FP_LATE_REGISTRATION'' JOIN webapps_base.salespartner br ON br.id = eat.fk_bringersalespartner_id WHERE eat.id = CAST(:id AS BIGINT)', 2);

insert into SYM_TRANSFORM_COLUMN (
  transform_id, include_on, target_column_name, source_column_name, pk,
  transform_type, transform_expression, transform_order) 
values ('eventattendee2fphist', '*', 'STADT_NR', 'fk_Person_ID', 0, 'lookup', 'select ag.agencynumber FROM webapps_base.salespartner sp join webapps_base.salespartneragencystructure sag on sp.id = sag.fk_salespartner_member join webapps_base.agency ag on ag.id = sag.fk_agency_id where sp.fk_person_id = CAST(:fk_person_id AS BIGINT)', 3);

insert into SYM_TRANSFORM_COLUMN (
  transform_id, include_on, target_column_name, source_column_name, pk,
  transform_type, transform_expression, transform_order) 
values ('eventattendee2fphist', '*', 'DATUM', 'id', 0, 'lookup', 'select e.eventdate FROM webapps_base.eventattendee eat JOIN webapps_base.event e ON e.id = eat.fk_event_id WHERE eat.id = CAST(:id AS BIGINT)', 4);
```

Comment: Let me try understanding your question. There's a table A both on source and target node. There's a column b on the table A of boolean type. If there's an insert at the source of a row in the table A with b==true you want the row to get inserted in the target node as well.

Comment: I don't understand what kind of behavior is required when b==false. Do you want to skip the synchronization of newly inserted row?

Comment: no, the table A is not available on target. i have a table "event_attendees" on source with a boolean column "attended". The insert case is not important, only "updates" on source. If the attended was set to true i want to create a "protocoll-entry" on target and if switched back to false i want to delete these possibly created "protocoll-entry".

Comment: Is there a transformation from source table A to target table M? Is there a routing defined?

Comment: I would suggest to create a table "protocol-entry" at the source with a column that will identify target node identity and let the application code at the source insert/delete "protocol-entry" rows. Then use routing to sync "protocol-entry" insertions/deletions to respecrive target nodes using column base routing. Does it make sense?

Comment: i've implemented this as a new feature for symmetricDS. You can setup an "update_action" like the existing "delete_action" but with support for bsh-scripts where you can return "INS_COL", "UPD_COL", "DEL_COL" from you bsh script. You can access the column values inside the script.

Comment: See http://www.symmetricds.org/issues/view.php?id=2367 for my patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's possible now with my own enhancement to [symmetricDS](http://www.symmetricds.org/issues/view.php?id=2367) and my branch at [github](https://github.com/NiasSt90/symmetric-ds/commit/c550bd21e5de4f84723383dd02c2f1037f132f84)